# RDS Postgres chicken-and-egg problem altering roles

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I just created an RDS Postgres instance, the user `postgres` (and it's master password), and connected via psql as user `postgres`.

Then I ran the script generated from the current system using `pg_dumpall --schema-only`, and it immediately failed on the `ALTER ROLE` commands:

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
```

Ok, but how do I grant `superuser` to `postgres`?  All of the documentation I've found "conveniently" skips that part...

EDIT: Here are the exact commands and error message:

```
postgres=> CREATE ROLE "READONLY";
CREATE ROLE
postgres=> ALTER ROLE "READONLY" WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'mdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
```

Comment: If you are using RDS, then you don't.  Is it necessary?  Are there follow-on errors?

Comment: @jjanes you don't alter roles in RDS (only create them)????  The AWS docs show `ALTER ROLE` commands being successfully executed.

Comment: You don't grant superuser to postgres.  You can alter roles, just not in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RDS master user [is not a superuser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html).

> `ALTER ROLE` changes the attributes of a PostgreSQL role. [...]
>
> Roles having `CREATEROLE` privilege can change any of these settings except `SUPERUSER`, `REPLICATION`, and `BYPASSRLS`...

Omit incompatible settings from your `ALTER ROLE` command.

Comment: `postgres` can't alter what it doesn't have privs to alter (which makes perfect sense), even if what it's doing is saying "you *can't* do what I don't have permission to grant you!"  Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: Interpert it as "U Can't Touch This". Cue in MC Hammer at will.

Comment: @RonJohn That is the case, although it does seem to go against with the most straightforward interpretation of the docs and ERROR message.  Perhaps this could be improved.